# Change only one icon in a list of objects - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jsx, react-state

I want to be able to change the icon in a list of todos (see picture) from an exclamation mark, to a checkmark. That should happen if the user puts the finger on the icon, or the developer clicks with the mouse in the emulator.

Through the code below, I manage to change it, but the new icon only appears if I close the modal containing the list, and reopen it. So the modal does not re-render, neither partly nor in whole.

How can I make the changes appear live, immediately after I click the exclamation icon? I suspect it has to do with state, but it doesn't seem possible to create a React hook inside the map function. If I let onPress call a function, then the state is only known within that external function, and I don't know how to export it.

```
export const TeacherMessages = (props) => {
  return (
    <View
        style={[
        styles.borderBox,
        props.todos.length > 0 || props.notes.length > 0
            ? styles.whiteBox
            : null,
        ]}
    >
        {
            props.todos.map((todo) => (
                <View key={todo.id} style={styles.listNotes}>
                  <AntDesign
                      style={styles.listIcon}
                      onPress={() => todo.isChecked = true}
                      name={todo.isChecked ? "checksquare" : "exclamationcircle"}
                      color={todo.isChecked ? "green" : "red"}
                      size={18}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.listText}> {todo.description}</Text>
                </View>
              ))
        }

);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to store the todos array in a react hook so that way the changes you do to it becomes live instantly, You can have this changeTodo function in the parent component and pass it as props to call it from the child component with the index needed. I think this might help:

```
export const TeacherMessages = (props) => {
  const [todosArr, setTodosArr] = React.useState(props.todos)

  const checkTodo = (todoIndex) =>{
        let arr = [...todosArr]
        arr[todoIndex].isChecked= true
        setTodosArr(arr)
 }

  return (
    <View
        style={[
        styles.borderBox,
        todosArr.length > 0 || props.notes.length > 0
            ? styles.whiteBox
            : null,
        ]}
    >
        {
            todosArr.map((todo, index) => (
                <View key={todo.id} style={styles.listNotes}>
                  <AntDesign
                      style={styles.listIcon}
                      onPress={() => checkTodo(index)}
                      name={todo.isChecked ? "checksquare" : "exclamationcircle"}
                      color={todo.isChecked ? "green" : "red"}
                      size={18}
                  />
                  <Text style={styles.listText}> {todo.description}</Text>
                </View>
              ))
        }

);
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this tonight or tomorrow, and report back.